# External popup onclick to open only once per session

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, popup

I was able to duplicate the functional popup (coding is hell for me). The problem is that every time you click on the page. What's annoying. Is there a possibility for me as a  beginner, so that I can only open the window once for the site? It's for a wordpress page. The code I inserted into the body.
Well thank you
Here is the code I wrote

```
<javascript:void(0);" onClick="window.open('<?php echo "https://prehrajto.cz/hledej/" .  $post->post_title ."?cc=uga3bwln" ?>','prehrajto','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,');">
```

I try this code , its open once per session , but its blocked browser . It would not mind, it's not the onclick function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onClick=window.open('<?php echo "https://prehrajto.cz/hledej/".get_the_title()."?cc=uga3bwln" ?>','prehrajto','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,');
</script>
```

And my programming experience is zero. I have a problem to combine code and to work with cookies . Im lost .

Comment: Have you tried checking the date and then using an if statement to see if the date is something and setting a variable to true or 1? If the page loads again it’ll see that the variable is 1 or true and it won’t load again until the next day. Not near a computer so can’t help anymore than that.

Comment: Once only per session? Or once only ever for a user?

Comment: @Bibberty - good question. that question alone should point to the solution. - COOKIES

Comment: Only one per session.

Comment: I have problem with conjunction with the current code with cookie . I try this ,but not work 
'code' <?php session_start(); $inactive = 3600; $_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
    if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {   // reset the timer (*not tested)
         $_SESSION["timeout"] = time() -3600;
        // add popup code
<javascript:void(0);" onClick="window.open('<?php echo "https://prehrajto.cz/hledej/" .  $post->post_title ."?cc=uga3bwln" ?>','prehrajto','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,');">
    } }?>

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do that using cookies .

php has functions for dealing with cookies , mainly [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php.php) and companions

```
**/ Set a Cookie /* 

    add_action( 'init', 'set_mycookie' );
    function set_mycookie() {
    setcookie( 'cookiename', 'cookievalue', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN   );
    }

**/ Get a Cookie /*

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_mycookie' );
    function get_mycookie() {
    $myvar= isset( $_COOKIE['cookiename'] ) ? $_COOKIE['cookiename'] : 'cookie not set';

    }

**/ Delete or Unset /* 

    add_action( 'init', 'unset_mycookie' );
    function unset_mycookie() {
    setcookie( 'cookiename', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
    }
```

now, of course these are the most basic general examples, but you could use it with any set of conditions, ( like @Bibberty comment/question ) for example by session, by user, by day, by page, etc . whatever you want .

**Sidenote** - wp has dedicated functions for using cookies, mainly for auth and session management ( which wp does not do by default ). see [wp_set_auth_cookie()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) to learn more

**sidenote 2**
Also, regarding your code ...
embading php inside JS ( or viceversa...) is a bad practice.
wp has actually a very [cool and elegant function to deal with that](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), and if you really want to learn php/wp - you better start using it now

Comment: I know what you wrote, but I do not know how to do it.
I'm in the stage when I'm glad to modify some code and it works. :/

Answer (score 0):

Its done , 
I did a popup with a css class with a z-index, and I inserted a transparent image as a external link with _blank and onclick into body. Maybe unprofessional but functional

Answer (score -3):

you can do with partial javascript partial php,

1) Php Based Cookie - Session session check

2) Javascript : Cookie - LocalStorage based session check

Comment: It would be good to explain that further - could you provide code for even one of these cases?